# Biographical Sketches in NSF Postdoc application

Tags: nsf

I am applying for NSF postdoc and it is asking for Biographical Sketches ( [see part 14 in here](https://www.nsf.gov/mps/dms/MSPRF/MSPRF_Application_Instructions_FY20.pdf)) https://www.nsf.gov/mps/dms/MSPRF/MSPRF_Application_Instructions_FY20.pdf.

So I was wondering if we can upload our CV here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would follow the specific directions.

Trace the links back and you get to a full description of what they want.  It's on pages II-14 and II-15 of this document:  https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg19_1/nsf19_1.pdf

Give them exactly what is asked for, in order, and matching the directions.

No, not your CV.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But is there anywhere that we can upload the CV?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not just upload your CV in place of the Biographical Sketch. The NSF has certain formatting requirements that the Biographical Sketch is supposed to adhere to, there are certain sections that must be present, certain information that is not supposed to be included, etc. For precise instructions about how to prepare your Biographical Sketch, see [here](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg19_1/pappg_2.jsp#IIC2f).